# JavaFX - How to change default date of DatePicker when clicking Calendar Icon?

Tags: javafx

I'm using **JFXDatePicker** extends **DatePicker** and want to change default date when clicking Calendar Icon.

- The default is the current date and I want to change it to a specific date
  by code (It will save a little time when choosing a date in 195x for
  example. I disable the Editable so can't type in textfield) And I
  don't want to use `.setvalue()` because it will display that date when
  the form was called.
- I've used this code but didn't work.

  `birthday = new JFXDatePicker(LocalDate.of(1980, Month.MARCH, 11));`

[http://i228.photobucket.com/albums/ee83/ThamVanTam/JFXDatePicker_zpscdgns2b6.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify @KirantosTera's code by listening to the pickers `showingProperty` then clearing the editor using `Platform.runLater()`

```
JFXDatePicker jfxDatePicker = new JFXDatePicker();
jfxDatePicker.showingProperty().addListener((observableValue, wasFocused, isNowFocus) -> {
    if (isNowFocus && jfxDatePicker.getValue() == null) {
        jfxDatePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now().minusYears(18));
        Platform.runLater(()->{
            jfxDatePicker.getEditor().clear();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: working and good as a hack :) Note though, that editor content and picker value are out of sync - most of the time not a problem because users will select a date differnt from the fake value, but if by any chance they want to select that fake value, the editor remains cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no public api to navigate in the popup content. That's supported by an internal class DatePickerContent, which has a method `goToDate(LocalDate, boolean)`. If you are allowed (and daring enough :) to use internals, you can do so in a onShown handler (to make certain that skin's onShowing listener doesn't interfere):

```
datePicker.setOnShown(e -> {
    if (datePicker.getValue() == null && datePicker.getSkin() instanceof DatePickerSkin) {
        DatePickerSkin skin = (DatePickerSkin) datePicker.getSkin();
        DatePickerContent popupContent = (DatePickerContent) skin.getPopupContent();
        popupContent.goToDate(LocalDate.now().minusYears(18), true);
    }
});
```

Note that this requires to open `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.DatePickerContent`

Comment: This method works only on the default DatePicker, can you provide a sample to external jars like JFoenix?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it's not perfect but still good for my issue:

```
        //Setting datepicker :
        birthday.setDayCellFactory(picker -> new DateCell() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                //Setting date 18 years ago
                LocalDate today = LocalDate.ofYearDay(LocalDate.now().getYear() - 18, LocalDate.now().getDayOfYear());
                //Disable future date
                setDisable(empty || date.compareTo(today) > 0);
            }
        });
        //Setting actual value
        birthday.setValue(LocalDate.ofYearDay(LocalDate.now().getYear() - 18, LocalDate.now().getDayOfYear()));
        //Cover the value by text
        String pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        formatCalender.format(pattern, birthday);
        birthday.getEditor().setText("Date Of Birth");
        birthday.setPromptText(null);
```